# Do I need visa to transit through the UK or EU countries?

Tags: uk, schengen, transit-visas, ghanaian-citizens, canadian-residents

I am a Ghanian and am a Canadian permanent resident. Can I transit without a visa through the UK and any EU country on my way to Ghana (such as Amsterdam, Belgium, Italy, Germany)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends...for ex. here in Germany, if you flight to your destiny, there are airports with a "transit-zone" and you, as ghanian with a visum in Canada, can use this transitzones to go from flight to flight, but you cannot leave the transit-zone. Not all airports have this transit-zones.

If you drive by car or take a train then you would need a transit-visa.

I suppose the laws in other EU-countries should not differ a lot from them here in Germany.

You also are making a very generall question, and I recommend you to take a look at the laws in the countries you are going to pass through.